# Make elements wrap in groups, not one by one

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

I have six inline, fixed-size elements and would like to wrap them so that each row has the same number of elements. So with a wide container, there would be 1 row with 6 columns / elements. As the container shrinks, it will go to 2x3, then 3x2, and finally 1x6.

My intuition is that I should be using flexbox, but I can't figure out how to stop it from wrapping one element at a time, giving me situations where there's 5 elements in the first row and 1 element in the second.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/59wgsk2s/1/

Comment: the solution is : media query

Answer (score 6):

Because your items are fixed-size, getting them to wrap as pairs or a larger multiple is a bit tricky.

The simple way to get multiple items to wrap is by setting their length in percentages. Then, using media queries, the number of items per row can be controlled by adjusting the percentages.

In a layout with, let's say six items (like your layout), widths could be set to 16% for desktop views.

```
[ 16% ] [ 16% ] [ 16% ] [ 16% ] [ 16% ] [ 16% ]
```

Then, for a laptop view, a media query can kick in, changing the widths to 33%:

```
[ 33% ] [ 33% ] [ 33% ]
[ 33% ] [ 33% ] [ 33% ]
```

Same idea for a tablet view:

```
[ 50% ] [ 50% ]
[ 50% ] [ 50% ]
[ 50% ] [ 50% ]
```

Same again for a mobile view:

```
[ 100% ]
[ 100% ]
[ 100% ]
[ 100% ]
[ 100% ]
[ 100% ]
```

Here's an illustration:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59wgsk2s/4/)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box div {
  flex: 1 0 15%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px) {
  .box div {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .box div {
    flex-basis: 40%;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 400px) {
  .box div {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
```

Of course, the problem with the demo above, as it relates to your question, is that the items don't have fixed width. As percentages, they are flexible.

So let's try the reverse approach: Instead of adjusting the size of the items, let's adjust the size of the container. By shrinking the container (with media queries), we can control the wrapping behavior *and* keep the fixed-width size of each item:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59wgsk2s/3/)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 360px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.box div {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px) {
  .box {
    width: 180px;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    width: 120px;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 400px) {
  .box {
    width: 60px;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
```

So if you can use either flexible lengths on the items, or shrink the width of the container, then your problem is solved. However, if neither are an option, then here's a clean and simple solution using CSS Grid Layout.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59wgsk2s/6/)

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px) {
  .box {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  }
}

@media ( max-width: 400px) {
  .box {
    grid-template-columns: 50px;
  }
}

.box div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If your container is of unknown width , may be you can use a little hack.

Here, I am inserting a pseudo element to force a break at the correct dimensions.

All you need is a forced break between the 3rd and the 4th elements, the other breaks are *natural*

I am forcing a break using 2 pseudos, the first one forces the break and the second has the adequate margin to make them *disappear* in the final layout

Just to make the snippet easy to follow, I have set the height of the pseudos to a non zero value. In production, set it to zero.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.box div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}
.box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  margin-left: calc(-50% + 20px);
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.box div:nth-child(n + 4) {
  order: 2;
}

#box6 {
  width: 370px;
}
#box5 {
  width: 310px;
}
#box4 {
  width: 250px;
}
#box3 {
  width: 190px;
}
#box2 {
  width: 130px;
}
#box1 {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box6">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</div>
```